# Mysql select non empty column

Tags: mysql

If the mysql table for the gallery looks like:

```
    id     |    pic1    |   pic2    |    pic3    |     pic4    
 -------------------------------------------------------------
    1      |            |   b.jpg   |    c.jpg   |     d.jpg
```

How can I select the first non empty pic value from columns pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4 for the gallery with id=1?

In example above it will be value from the pic2 column (b.jpg)

Comment: What if all pic columns are empty?

Comment: I think you will have to do it at application level

Comment: @Programmer - at least one of the columns must be filled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4, 'backup.gif') AS pic
FROM gallery
WHERE id = 1
```

`backup.gif` will be returned if all are empty.  This also assumed that by *empty* the columns are *NULL*.

Comment: I'm doubting it's a poltergeist.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COALESCE( pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4 ) AS pic
FROM gallery
WHERE id = 1;
```

Assuming you used `NULL` to represent an empty value, as opposed to blanks

Comment: @Moo-Juice you must type faster than I ;)

Answer (score 0):

Would be interesting to understand why you are structuring your data in such an inflexible way in the database?